# how to determine html input files sequence

Tags: html

So, let's say this is the code I used in my html from W3CSCHOOL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Select images: <input type="file" name="img" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p>Try selecting more than one file when browsing for files.</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The multiple attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The action_page.php is going to display the files you have selected. But it will display it by name orders, not the selection orders. I am wondering if there is anyway to change the sequence of the file? Maybe based on the selection order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no selection order.
The files are all being chosen all together.

You can dynamically add more image inputs as far as the user asks for.